# Raising a sparse matrix to an integer number

Tags: python, matrix, google-colaboratory, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am required to transform my matrix into a sparse matrix using csr_matrix()

After doing that I was hoping to raise it to the power of 10 by using np.linalg.matrix_power() (multiplying the matrix by itself 10 times)

However it seems like np.linalg.matrix_power() does not work for the sparse matrix

I found a method which is .power() but I do not think they are the same thing

Are there any suggestion on what I can do to handle the sparse matrix?

Comment: Which kind of multiply?  element-wise or matrix?

Comment: `np.linalg.matrix_power` does repeated matrix multiplications, with some grouping to save effort.  And as a general rule `np` functions don't work on sparse matrices unless they delegate the task to the matrix's own methods.

Comment: @hpaulj matrix wise

Comment: `M@M@M...` or maybe `M2=M@M; M2@M2@....`

Comment: `M**10` works because sparse matrix power is defined with matrix multiplication.